# How to get values for specific items in enum array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, enums

Continuing on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328929/how-to-check-an-input-against-many-different-potential-options-each-with-a-sepa) I've been looking into and messing around with enums a bit, and now I've managed to create an enum that holds the values I want and outputs them in the way I want, now I'd just like to know how I could get the same output but for a single item rather than every item. Again, I'm very new to Java so a simple explanation as to how and why would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class PeriodicTable {

    public enum Element {
        Lithium("Li", "Alkali Metals", 6.941),
        Iron("Fe", "Transition Metals", 55.933);
        private String symbol;
        private String group;
        private Double weight;

        private Element(String symbol, String group, Double weight) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.group = group;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(Element cName : Element.values()) {
            System.out.println("Element: " + cName + " (" + cName.symbol + ")" + "\nGroup: " + cName.group + "\nAtomic Weight: " + cName.weight);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `valueOf` method passing in the user input to retrieve the enum:

```
Element ele = Elements.valueOf(input);
```

And then you can use your print statement to print the info:

```
Element cName = Element.valueOf("Iron");
System.out.println("Element: " + cName + " (" + cName.symbol + ")" + "\nGroup: " + cName.group + "\nAtomic Weight: " + cName.weight);
```

***Output:***

```
Element: Iron (Fe)
Group: Transition Metals
Atomic Weight: 55.933
```

Comment: Why not just `Element cName = Element.Iron;`?

Comment: @Andreas The OP is trying to allow user input, and the input will be a `String`, so the `valueOf` method is necessary. I just used "Iron" as an example to show how it would work

Comment: Nothing in the question says anything about "user input". It just says *"for a single item"*. `Element.Iron` is one way to get a "single item". It is simpler than `valueOf`, and it is type-safe, i.e. you cannot misspell the enum value name (or rather, compiler will tell you immediately if you did).

Comment: @Andreas It says it is continuing from their previous question, which shows that they are trying to get user input and get the corresponding element